# addObserver on self

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing, self, addobserver

A pretty simple question, but I can't seem to find an answer. (Developing an iOS 5+ app).

In my *AppDelegate*, I have a property, let's call it `@property (non atomic) BOOL aFlag;`. I'd like my *AppDelegate* to be notified if the value changes. Here is what I tried (everything happens in the `AppDelegate.m`), which is the same as when I "link" two different objects with an observer :

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application 
       didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions {
    // Some stuff

    _aFlag = YES;
    [self addObserver:self 
           forKeyPath:@"aFlag" 
              options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld) 
              context:nil];

    // Some other stuff
}


-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath 
                     ofObject:(id)object 
                       change:(NSDictionary*)change 
                      context:(void*)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqual:@"aFlag"]) {
        // Do something
    } else {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

But `observeValueForKeyPath:` is not called.

Where am I wrong ? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should implement your own setter. In that setter you know the poperty has changed.

It's more optimised that way. Much better and less expensive then doing KVO on yourself.

Your solution works, technically you can KVO yourself.

But, imagine if you started using `NSNotificationCenter` for triggering methods in you class from inside your class? Can it be done? Yes. Should it be? Probably not. You may have a scenario where it's okay but not in a clean object oriented solution. You should be messaging `self` for this.

Well it's the same here. Implement this:

```
- (void)setAFlag:(BOOL)flag;
```

For example:

```
- (void)setAFlag:(BOOL)flag{
    BOOL valueChanged = NO;    

    if(_aFlag != flag){
       valueChanged = YES;
    }
    _aFlag = flag;

    if(valueChanged)
        [self doSomethingWithTheNewValueOfFlag];
}
```

Comment: Well, that's a great answer. I didn't think of that, and it seems more efficient than the KVO solution. The only thing is I have five flags to observe... Which means I either need to implement 5 setters, or use a single method with all the flags (may be nicer). Thanks for the advice !

Comment: this is an awesome answer bool in bool